# Obtaining the index from a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I have the following situation:

My variable *params* is composed by several sub-values:

```
>> params
rec.array([ (12.534214167520581, ... 0.7833572386219857, -0.4215128074913047,  3.717773146160369)], 
      dtype=[('const', '<f8'), ('ampl', '<f8'), ('freq', '<f8'), ('phase', '<f8'), ('e_const', '<f8'), ('e_ampl', '<f8'), ('e_freq', '<f8'), ('e_phase', '<f8'), ('stopcrit', '<f8')])
```

however I'm interested only in *ampl* and *freq*, the values for them are:

```
>>params['ampl']
array([ 12.53421417,  22.53421417,  21.53421417, ...,  2.53421417,
    1.53421417,  2.53421417])

>>params['freq']
array([  0.78335724,   1.56697824,   4.86322084, ...,  11.45392432,
    21.17763437,   0.4946571 ])
```

After some analysis I realized that the only values of interest are the ones with *ampl* *22.53421417* and *21.53421417*.

Let's call these values *new_array = [22.53421417, 21.53421417]*, What I need is to create a new *params['ampl']* and *params['freq']* but only with the values of my interest, in other words, reduce *params['ampl']* and *params['freq']* to:

```
params['ampl'] = [22.53421417, 21.53421417]
params['freq'] = [1.56697824,   4.86322084]
```

In addition, these are the type of data:

```
>>type(params)
numpy.recarray     

>>type(params['ampl'])
numpy.ndarray
```

I have tried several things using *.index* but just don't work. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the arrays are ordered such that `params['amp'][0]` and `params['freq'][0] are relating to a singular object with amplitude and frequency we can do the following.

```
imp_amp = [22.53421417, 21.53421417]
for i in imp_amp:
    loc_in_amp = param['amp'].index(i) #get each values location in amp
    values_you_want = param['freq'][loc_in_amp] #grab the frequency for that value
    #do whatever you want with the values.
```

A convenient one-liner that creates a new dict, amp:freq.

```
n_param = {i:param['freq'][param['amp'].index(i)] for i in imp_amp}
print n_param

#   {22.53421417: 1.56697824, 
#    21.53421417: 4.86322084}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but when I run the code, I obtain the same error I have been receiving:  Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-21-aa025344e300>", line 2, in <module>
    loc_in_amp = params['ampl'].index(i) #get each values location in amp

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: You didn't specify that you were using a numpy array.

Comment: Provide the code used to create the array, and the data passed.

Comment: Thanks, yes, sorry for not mention that, params is created using a function from a lib to process signals, all that we know is that we have a numpy array and we need to identify the index based on a value:   type(params)  = numpy.recarray      type(params['ampl']) = numpy.ndarray

Comment: Thanks! I was able to solve it using `np.where` and `np.around` to reduce the decimals of the float numbers.